# ImportError: cannot import name uuid4

Tags: python, pycharm

```
#-*- encoding: utf-8 -*-

__author__ = 'Administrator'
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

def parse_row(input_row, parsers):
    """given a list of pasers (some of which may be None)
    apply the appropriate one to each element of the input_row"""
    return [parser(value) if parser is not None else value
             for value, parser in zip(input_row, parsers)]

if __name__ == "__main__":
    url = "http://news.china.com.cn/2015-10/28/content_36911585.htm"
    soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url.strip()).text, 'html5lib')
```

it is my code above in pycharm IDE.The error is

```
"Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "D:\Program Files\PyCharm Community Edition 4.5.4\helpers\pydev\pydevd.py", line 98, in <module>

    from pydevd_plugin_utils import PluginManager

  File "D:\Program Files\PyCharm Community Edition 

4.5.4\helpers\pydev\pydev_monkey_qt.py", line 71, in patched_import

    return original_import(name, *args, **kwargs)

  File "D:\Program Files\PyCharm Community Edition 

4.5.4\helpers\pydev\pydevd_plugin_utils.py", line 5, in <module>

    from _pydev_imps._pydev_pluginbase import PluginBase

  File "D:\Program Files\PyCharm Community Edition 

4.5.4\helpers\pydev\pydev_monkey_qt.py", line 71, in patched_import

    return original_import(name, *args, **kwargs)

  File "D:\Program Files\PyCharm Community Edition 

4.5.4\helpers\pydev\_pydev_imps\_pydev_pluginbase.py", line 20, in <module>

    from uuid import uuid4

ImportError: cannot import name uuid4"
```

Comment: You have a backtick after `import requests`; is that a copy-paste error?

Comment: Manually, at Python chevron prompt `>>>` do just `import uuid`. This will tell if the module is in PYTHONPATH.

Comment: To respond to my comment: no, that's a case of not using code blocks, then a mistake in an edit to correct that.

Comment: Somehow, the traceback doesn't seem to be related to the code given: I don't see any line in the traceback that corresponds to a line in the code.

Comment: you are right @flamenco.it is succeed that i execute "import uuid" in prompt `>>>`.But why does it is error in pycharm.

Comment: It is occured "error ImportError: cannot import name uuid4" of error when I execute `import requests` at Python chevron prompt `>>>`

Comment: It can be more than one root cause...In `Settings` make sure that you have the right interpreter selected. You might have more than one Python versions installed on your machine.

Answer (score 4):

Are you sure you dont have a python file named **uuid.py** in your project directory?

Never name your python files after python modules ;)